# How to create Two Week View of Calendar in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-calendar

There is an option of Week View when I am using the Calendar web part, it is showing One week view. I want to create Two(2) week view of Calendar.

How can I create Two week view of Calendar? Is there any option to modify View using XSLT or similar?

Please help.